# Grails pass data to view from controller

Tags: grails

Hi i made a ajax request to my controller already. Can my controller send back data as normal
eg.

```
[p:project]
```

I want to reload google map markers

Comment: You'll need to provide more information if you want quality answers.  Try including what you've tried and what errors your getting.

Comment: Guys, sometimes these questions are useful for people starting a new framework since not everything is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to rending something back in ajax controller method.  Assuming you have a gsp template called "_project.gsp" it could look something like this...

```
def project = Project.get(params.id);
render(template:"project" model:['p':project]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Let say you want to send the project obj back as a result to the view "projectView" , you can do something like that in your controller

```
render(view : "projectView", model:[p:project]);
```

Then "consuming" the result within your view as below (where p is the name of the variable you send from the controller

```
<html><head>Test</head><body>${p}</body></html>
```