# HTTP GET request in Grails with urls

Tags: grails, httprequest, grails-controller

I've got a problem using a HTTP GET request in Grails with urls. My plan is to read saved params out of an url. Like there is a param called address with saved content. For example: http://mydomain.de/property?address=Alexanderplatz+3%2C+Berlin%2C+Deutschland=&submit=start . 
Here I commit my entered address into a url. There's another page, on which I'm going to be redirected after clicking the submit-button, and there is a form with an inputfield named "address". In this inputfield I'd like to commit the saved address from the given url as a default value. Do I need to configure the controller of my grails-app in a special way? I have the following function:

```
def create() {
    render(view: "form")
}
```

How is it possible to do a HTTP GET request in Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the perfect solution right here: [Grails pass data to view from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772761/grails-pass-data-to-view-from-controller)

in PropertiyController.groovy:

```
def index = { 

    def parameter = 
    request.getParameter("address") 
   }
```

and:

```
def create() {
    def address = params.address;

    render(view: "form", model:[viewAddress:address]);
}
```

The only thing to change additional is to give the input-field the missung param linke this:

```
value="${viewAddress}"
```

It works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

For those stumbling across this question later, like I did.

It looks like HTTPBuilder has a new version out for Grails 3:

https://github.com/http-builder-ng/http-builder-ng

And some great examples here:

https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/

Answer (score 2):

Use [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/home.html):

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')

http.get( path : '/search',
      contentType : TEXT,
      query : [q:'Groovy'] ) { resp, reader -> 
  println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
  System.out << reader
}
```

Update:

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  ...
  dependencies {
    compile( 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2' ){ excludes 'groovy', 'xercesImpl' }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I have to include this HttpBuilder? - in the controller-file?

Comment: you can include it anywhere you like. controller or service seem to be reasonable options.

Comment: ok. But after creating http as a new variable like you have written overhead there is an error called "unexpected token: http". It seems to be that the new variable isn´t accepted or am I wrong?

Comment: you have to include the dependency into your `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: do you have an example for me how the code has to be written? it´s the first time for me working with grails ...

Comment: your solution doesn´t work. But I´ve found a way to get to my aim. Thanks anyway!